# How Secure Is This?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I want to be able to give strict access to specific users to my web page, not BY IP; but through Javascript and HTML.

How easy will it be to get the security string?

```
function fc4me(srvstr) {

   if(!document.pleazfc4me.email.value || !document.pleazfc4me.securitystring.value) {
      alert("Please fill in all the required fields!");
      return false;
   }
   if(document.pleazfc4me.securitystring.value != hexMD5("\x73\x73"+srvstr)) {
      alert("Registration Authorization String not accepted! Try Harder! ");
      return false;
    } else {
      document.pleazfc4me.submit();
    }

}
```

and the other page?

```
Security String<font color="orange">*</font>:
<input type="text" name="securitystring" size="35">
<input onClick="var srvstr='foo';fc4me(srvstr);document.pleazfc4me.securitystring.value='';return false;" name="submit" type="image" src="images/button-submit.png" />
```

Comment: font tags? It is not 1999. They are deprecated.

Comment: it doesn't matter. `document.pleazfc4me.submit();` in the console and you bypass your checks altogether.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. But that doesn't really answer my question now.. Does it?

Comment: Not secure at all.  Do all verification server-side.

Comment: @sachleen So not that secure at all? even know it looks for a MD5 string of a decrypted hexidecimal + srvstr

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @user1902584 checking the md5 is meaningless if I can directly execute code that it tries to block me from.

Comment: Its also not necessary to use swears in your code. Doesn't help anyone, doesn't look professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. `document.pleazfc4me.submit();` in the console and you bypass your checks altogether.

I could just as easily turn off JS altogether and the form would submit as default behavior.

You can use as much obfuscation as you want but unless you do some check in the **server side** code to reject an unauthorized user, anyone can bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

It is secure for only people that are not smart enough to view your source code. Heck, turn off JavaScript and the form submits.

Comment: In fact, don't I simply have to hit <enter> in the text input field, since the "security" check is attached to an `onclick` handler?

Answer (score 1):

Doing anything client side *won't* be secure. You should have server side checks for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in javascript is just field validation, doesn't actually add to the security of the page. You can always check the parameters in the page you are submitting to before you start processing the request. That will reduce roundabout time.

You can even use AJAX to validate the fields, if you want to show the message in the same page itself.